# What type of VBA variable/object is DataFile in this code?

Tags: vba, excel, types

This code is part of a macro where the user chooses a folder containing data files. This function then lists all of the files in the chosen folder in a listbox from which the user can choose specific files to process. The code is working fine, I am just wondering what 'DataFile' is/is doing. It isn't declared as a variable anywhere in any of the code. Is it a built in predefined object or just a variant type that is declared/initialized in the For loop?

```
Sub ListMyFiles(SourcePath)

    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set MySource = MyObject.GetFolder(SourcePath)

    nfile = 0

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each DataFile In MySource.Files
        If ((InStr(DataFile.Name, ".xlsx")) Or (InStr(DataFile.Name, ".xls"))) Then
            nfile = nfile + 1
            ListFilesTxt.AddItem (DataFile.Name)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If it is not declared it by default a variant, but as soon as it is used in the for each loop it gets defined as a file type object.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not declared then by default it starts its life as a variant type so it can be felxible enough to hold whatever is put into it.

Once it's used in the `for each` loop, it becomes a file object type as it's used in a way as to refer to the files in mysource.files.

It's like the oft used `for i = 1 to 10` where i isn't explicitly declared as anything. Variable `i` starts its life as a variant and as soon as it's given the values of 1 to 10 to iterate through, it becomes an integer variable to hold the values between 1 and 10.

Or another oft used example `for each cell in range("A1:C20").cells` again the `cell` variable if not explicitly declared starts as a variant and becomes a range variable of size 1 to hold the reference of each cell as needed in the loop.

Comment: Worth noting that an undeclared variable is forever and always a Variant, it may behave like like the type int in your `for` example but internally its a Variant containing an int. Its also free to mutate itself from say an int to a long as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very helpful. This is what I figured was going on.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK, very true and a worthwhile note!